# Polymer 3 error - how to configure Rollup --inlineDynamicImport option

Tags: polymer, rollupjs, polymer-3.x

I am getting the following error after adding dynamic imports (required for the use case) when trying to build using polymer tools:

```
info:   Clearing build/ directory...
error:  Promise rejection: Error: Failed to bundle.  Rollup generated 2 chunks or assets.  Expected 1.
error:  Error: Failed to bundle.  Rollup generated 2 chunks or assets.  Expected 1.
    at Es6Rewriter.<anonymous> (/home/suared/localdev/nodespace/ui/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-bundler/lib/es6-rewriter.js:138:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/suared/localdev/nodespace/ui/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-bundler/lib/es6-rewriter.js:4:58)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I found a potential solution in the Rollup docs and the web that referenced this problem being fixed when passing `--inlineDynamicImports` to the Rollup command.  I have not found away to pass this as part of the build process, however.  I tried this:

```
polymer build --auto-base-path --inlineDynamicImport
```

It reported the error that it is an unknown option. I also tried placing this in the `polymer.json` as part of the bundle config, unsuccessfully; it doesn't look like it is actually passed to Rollup:

```
      "bundle": {
        "inlineCss": true,          
        "inlineScripts": true,      
        "rewriteUrlsInTemplates": true, 
        "sourcemaps": true,     
        "stripComments": true,
        "--inlineDynamicImport": true    
      }
```

What is the correct way to pass to the Polymer build tools the `--inlineDynamicImport` option so that I only get one file and therefore will avoid the "2 chunks" error?

Answer (score 0):

If it helps others till I get a real answer, this workaround worked for me:

Local monkey patch/ update of the following file:
node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polymer-bundler/lib/es6-rewriter.js:74

In the call that reads like the first line, manually add the configuration, leave the rest of the config as-is:

```
            const rollupBundle = yield rollup_1.rollup({
                input,
                external,
                onwarn: (warning) => { },
                treeshake: this.bundler.treeshake,
                inlineDynamicImports: true, ....(rest of existing command
```

Any assistance on the right way using the build tools is welcome/ appreciated.

Thanks!
David